# how to auto open an entity created in a workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have run into a situation where I need to open a newly created quote at the end of a workflow. I have a feeling this is going to require me to create a a very simple custom workflow that uses "window.open", but I would like to avoid this if anyone has a better idea.

So I need to open a newly created quote as soon as it is created in a workflow. Anyone have any good ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Workflows are *asynchronous*; they run on the *server* (as opposed to the client) and do not run in realtime. eg a workflow that is triggered by creation of a record will run on the server sometime *after* the record is created (depending on system load etc - it could be a second or two, or could be half an hour later. If you have stopped the CRM Async service on the server, they might well never run.)

Because they run on the server the user has no interaction with them. As a result you can't open a window, as there's no user involved to open a window for...

What you probably want to do is make use of **Dialogs** (introduced in CRM 2011). You won't be able to use `window.open()` but as long as you've got a recent update rollup installed on the server you can present the user with a hyperlink to most CRM records.

Setup of Dialogs  is much the same as Workflows, and they use the same mechanics under the hood. The difference is that they're syncronous (i.e. run in real-time) and they are client-side. There's some detail on Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334463.aspx